# Extraneous output of org-mode inline source block results in org

Tags: org-mode

Context:

M-x org-version => Org-mode version 8.3.1 (8.3.1-95-g1dbb25-elpaplus @ /Users/username-here/elisp/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20150831/)

Executing:

```
src_R[:results value]{sin(0)}
```

Yields:

```
{{{results(=0=)}}}
```

Before I updated to this latest version of org-plus-contrib, i.e., when I was using org from git source, it yielded:

```
=0=
```

Have others run into this (my google search didn't yield anthing)? Can you help me determine the issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a problem? It should export to LaTeX/HTML just fine...

Comment: You are right, it does export fine. Do you happen to know the reason for the change, just curious?